# In Scala,Why is it not possible to change the value of var variable with different datatype

Tags: scala

I am learning scala, trying to understand var variable .

Look at my below code

```
scala> var id =10
id: Int = 10

scala> id ="surender"
<console>:12: error: type mismatch;
 found   : String("surender")
 required: Int
   id ="surender"
```

var is mutable, that means we can change the value, While changing the value do we need to stick with same datatype?

Does it mean statically typed language?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes Scala is indeed a statically typed language. You can't reassign the data type at runtime.

The concept is called type safety and a lot people value it deeply. It is a matter of preference however.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the type when creating a `var` (or a `val`):

```
var id: Any = 10 // Don't actually do this!
id = "surender" // works
```

If you don't, the compiler *infers* the type from the initializer (in this case type of `10` is `Int`). However, Scala is indeed statically typed and there is very little you can usefully do with something of type `Any`. This is more useful e.g. in this situation:

```
var x: Option[Int] = None
x = Some(10) // doesn't compile without the signature above
```